# How to make lightning components auto resize in outlook?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

I have developed a lightning component for outlook and I'm wondering if there is a way to get the component to automatically resize when the user drags the side bar. The other components resize automatically but I can't find any documentation on what would be able to do this.

Some people have mentioned flexiPage or using `aura:attribute name="width"` to change the size of each  tag but that seems excessive. Surely there's something you can put in the style component to do this for you. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Aura:

```
<aura:component controller="EAP_Project_Class" implements="clients:availableForMailAppAppPage,clients:hasItemContext">


    <aura:attribute name="retProjects" type="list"/>
    <aura:attribute name="tell" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="tell1" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}" />

  <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default" >  

      <!--////////////////heading and lightning icon//////////////-->

        <lightning:layout >
            <lightning:layoutItem >
                <lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom16" />
            </lightning:layoutItem>

            <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-m-left--small">
                 <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-p-right--x-small">Projects ({!v.retProjects.length}) </h1>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>

      <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

      <table class="slds-table ">
          <tbody> {!v.people.from.email}
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.retProjects}" var="project" indexVar="index">
             <tr>
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!project.Name}">
                 <a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" data-index="{!index}">{!project.Name}
                 </a></div>
                  <div>&nbsp; Market: {!project.Market__c}</div>  
                  <div>&nbsp; Region: {!project.Region__c}</div>
             </tr>
         </aura:iteration>
         </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

CSS

```
.THIS{width:310px; padding: 10px; margin:12px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `<div>` tag around your entire component and Add `SLDS_Size` also remove any width tag from style component.